# want to create a subcategory.php to manage subcats

Tags: customization, php

Is it possible to create a `subcategory.php` and use it to manage subcategories?

Or is there a way to get around this?

If it is not possible.. is there something like this?

```
<?php if(is_subcategory() || child() ) {
//do stuff
} else {
// do else
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to create a subcategory.php, but you can do the following in your category.php:

```
$category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );

if( !empty( $category->parent ) ) { // the category has a parent, so it is a subcategory
    // do stuff
} else {
    // do else
}
```

Comment: hey sorich87...thank you very much.. i appreciate it greatly man.. keep up the good work..i wish u success